# Trying to get max-content of element's height plus some custom value

Tags: html, css

What i need is to add more height after max-content
I tried to use calc but its not working its not allowed to sum max-content with px or rem
here is my code

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting <br> industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer</p>
```

```
p{ 
  // Here were i need some additional space after max-content
  height: calc(max-content + 2rem)
}
```

Comment: can you post the whole code instead of a single line to get better idea to the community

Comment: `max-content` has an undefined value. The value is calculated while rendering... besides that, why not just add a bottom-padding to the element?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.